# Notepad++ insert to string

Tags: notepad++

Using notepad++ I have the following text

```
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdef
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyzxyz
```

I'd like to change:

```
[fplayer src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=abcdef"]
[fplayer src="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xyzxyz"]
```

what should I do?

Comment: What have you tried? What didn't work? What did you get? What did you expect?

Comment: The posted question does not appear to include any attempt at all to solve the problem. StackExchange expects you to try to solve your own problem first, as your attempts help us to better understand what you want. Please edit the question to show what you've tried, so as to illustrate a specific problem you're having in a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example. For more information, please see [How to Ask](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask) and [take the tour](https://superuser.com/tour).

Comment: Press Ctrl-H and do replace text.

Answer (score 0):

For your example, you can use a [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html) to replace each url with your modified version.

1. Open *Search → Replace* (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> +  <kbd>H</kbd> ).
2. In the `Find what:` field enter `(^https.+)`.
3. In the `Replace with` field enter `[fplayer src="$1"]`.
4. Make certain that *Search Mode → Regular expression* is marked. `Match case` and `. matches newline` should be left unchecked.

[image: Notepad++ - Screenshot]

- `^https.+` means to look for lines beginning with `https` which have one or more characters afterwards (`.+` in this case matches the whole line).<sup>1</sup>
- `()` means to consider the match as a single group.
- `$1` is a replacement meaning "enter the first match group here" (i.e. whatever is matched by `^https.+`).

---

<sup>1</sup> *Technically, `^` isn't really necessary in this instance. `Find what` could just be `(https.+)`.*

---